# How to get context of another activity which is not started yet ?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-fragmentactivity

I want to use context of activity 'A' for start activity 'B' from activity 'C' where activity 'A' is never started yet.

I am using the below line but it is not working.

public static ContextActivityA aContext  = new ContextActivityA();

so is there any way to get context of another activity which is not started yet ?

Comment: "I want to use context of activity 'A' for start activity 'B' from activity 'C' where activity 'A' is never started yet" -- why?

Comment: make some `Static variable Context` and store `Activity context` on that and used. This is not gud idea.

Comment: @ CommonsWare : There is a scenario where I need to use context of activity 'A' for start activity 'B' from activity 'C' where activity 'A' is never started.

Comment: Starting an activity requires current Foreground context(UI context).You cannot do what you are asking for.

Comment: @ M D : can you please elaborate.

Comment: "There is a scenario" -- feel free to explain **completely and precisely** what this scenario is. Feel free to also document your proof that starting an activity using one `Context` has different results than starting an activity using some other `Context`. Feel free to explain how, in Java, you can use an object that does not yet exist, since clearly you feel that this is possible. Finally, feel free to explain how introducing a memory leak, via a `static` reference to `ContextActivityA`, is a good idea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no point or advantage to doing this.  Each `Activity` has its own lifecycle and its own version of `Context` which exists only for the activity's lifecycle.